# Testing composer.lock without changing anything

Tags: git, composer-php

I'm working on a Composer-managed project with git. I merged in some changes from other folks and got a merge conflict on the `composer.lock` file.

Once I have manually edited the file to resolve the conflict, is there a way I can test Composer before committing my changes, without actually updating anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, performing a `composer install` will install exactly the package versions from the `composer.lock` without updating to any newer version.

To test without changing `composer install --dry-run` will output the operations but will not execute anything.

Comment: Thanks! Also I found the `--dry-run` option which avoids changes

Comment: Yes of course you can use the `--dry-run` parameter. Added it to the answer.